# Is there a way to communicate between child_process.spawn and parent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm running a `gulp` command using `child_process.spawn` and I'm trying to send a message from gulp. So far I did

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
  done => {
    process.send({message: 'finished'})
    done()
  }
))
```

index.js

```
proc = spawn(path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/.bin/gulp'), ['--gulpfile', gulpFilePath], {
  cwd: data.projectPath,
  env: process.env,
  silent: true,
})
proc.on('message', msg => {
  console.log(msg)
})
```

but I'm not getting the message.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use fork instead of spawn: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should be able to send a message by setting option.stdio to `[ 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc' ]`